# Compliation missing dependencies

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, xrandr

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 and I'm following [this](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=159064). Once I run `autogen.sh` I get the following error

```
./configure: line 10337: --print-errors: command not found
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for floor in -lm... yes
./configure: line 10522: syntax error near unexpected token `XRANDR,'
./configure: line 10522: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(XRANDR, xrandr >= 1.5 xrender x11 xproto >= 7.0.17)'
```

I guess what I need to fix is the syntax error but I don't understand what the error is saying. Am I missing some dependencies? I have `xrandr` installed

```
xrandr --version
xrandr program version       1.5.0
Server reports RandR version 1.5
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps you need `libxrandr-dev`. Try `sudo apt-get install libxrandr-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I fixed it by installing the package `libglib2.0-dev`. I'm not sure if it was actually that package itself, or one of its dependencies, but either way that got it.